# sql query join with no doubles

Tags: mysql, sql

i am struggling with a query,  
**Table1**

```
startdate  | enddate   | name    | examination 
2020-02-01 | 2020-02-01| JohnDoe | xyz
```

**Table2**

```
begindate  | enddate    | name    | mutation 
2020-02-01 | 2020-02-07 | JohnDoe | Away
2020-03-01 | 2020-03-01 | JohnDoe | Away
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT a.begindate
     , a.enddate
     , IF((a.begindate BETWEEN b.begindate AND b.enddate ), b.mutation, a.exam) value
  FROM table1 a
  JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.name = b.name
```

**Result**

```
a.begindate | a.enddate  | value
2020-02-01  | 2020-02-01 | Away
2020-02-01  | 2020-02-01 | xyz
```

But i expect only to see *all records* from table1 and if the begindate from table 1 is between the begindate and enddate then show the value of table2.mutation without double records. tried left/right joins but without result.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Edit your question to show the desired result

Comment: Do you want to join only if that inner `if` results in a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` and set the condition `a.begindate between b.begindate and b.enddate` in the ON clause:

```
select 
  a.begindate, a.enddate, 
  case when b.name is not null then b.mutation else a.exam end as value
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b on a.name = b.name and a.begindate between b.begindate and b.enddate
```

Instead of the `case` expression you could also use:

```
coalesce(b.mutation, a.exam)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT a.begindate
       ,a.enddate
       ,b.mutation
       ,a.exam
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b 
    ON a.name = b.name 
    AND a.begindate BETWEEN b.begindate AND b.enddate
```

If you want to combine examination and mutation into a single field use a CASE statement:

`CASE WHEN b.mutation IS NOT NULL THEN b.mutation ELSE a.exam END AS value`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.startdate, t1.enddate, t1.name, t2.mutation
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.name = t2.name and
        t1.startdate <= t2.enddate and
        t1.startdate >= t2.startdate
```